# Using a callback once the geolocation has been found

Tags: javascript, callback, geolocation

I am writing a program a web service that records the location of a user. The program uses geolocation to find the user and once it retrieves the location then continues to record the location. Because geolocation uses a callback function to get the location the program cannot continue until it has the location. The problem is that i cannot continue the program within the geolocation function since other variables are needed. So what i have done is that the geoolcaion function displays the location on the web page using the following function

```
function geoFindMe(){
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, geo_options);
function success(position) {
var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
 var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
 var altitude = position.coords.altitude;
 var accuracy = position.coords.accuracy;
 var time = getTime();
 //post the everything somewhere and then the callback function will fetch the info 
 //may use var time = position.timestamp;
 $("#result").append(time + " " + latitude + " " + longitude); 
}

function error(error) {
 alert("Unable to retrieve your location due to "+error.code + " : " + error.message);
 }//there was a semicolon here

var geo_options = {
 enableHighAccuracy: true,
 maximumAge : 30000,
 timeout : 27000
 };
}
```

this function is called by the following code

```
 geoFindMe(function successful(){
        //first call geoFindMe function then call successful as a callback
        //the function will retrieve the information that was displayed by the geoFindMe on the webpage
            $("#result").hide();
            var currentLocation = document.getElementById('result');
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "";
            var moved = hasMoved(previousLocation, currentLocation);
            var time = isItTime(moved, lastBuffer, 15);
            if(time){//its time to put the location in the buffer
                currentLocation = currentLocation + "#";// this way we will be able to differentiate between different locations
                charBuffer.wrap(currentLocation);
            }
            dump(stringArray, lastDump, true);
        });
```

what i am trying to do is once the geolocation is found then call the successful function which i am trying to make a callback function. the problem is that for some reason it is skipping over most of the successful callback function and it continues with the line dump(...); any suggestions? perhaps i am not writing the successful function properly? thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add a parameter in the geoFindMe function to accept the callback. Then call it in the success function

```
function geoFindMe(callback){
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, geo_options);
  function success(position) {
     callback&&callback(); // Check if callback exists and then call it.
     var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
     var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
     var altitude = position.coords.altitude;
     var accuracy = position.coords.accuracy;
     var time = getTime();
     //post the everything somewhere and then the callback function will fetch the info 
     //may use var time = position.timestamp;
     $("#result").append(time + " " + latitude + " " + longitude); 
  }  
  function error(error) {
     alert("Unable to retrieve your location due to "+error.code + " : " + error.message);
  }//there was a semicolon here
  var geo_options = {
     enableHighAccuracy: true,
     maximumAge : 30000,
     timeout : 27000
  };
}
```